# Android How to correctly add several button listeners

Tags: java, android, actionlistener

I would like to ask you how to add several listeners to the several buttons in android.

1. Add one common listener and check which button invoked the listener.
2. Add mulitple anonymous listeners.
3. Add some methods which will be invoked(described in XML onClick property)

AD. 1 how to check which button called the listener(sth like e.getSource() where e is Event). I got this kind of code and it IS NOT NICE TO KEEP BUTTON AS A FIELD. How should i correct it? What are drawbacks of 3. option?

```
package com.example.fiszki;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    b.setText("kupa");      
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 are the most commonly used. I have very rarely seen 3 implemented. In 1, do differentiate between the buttons you will need an if statement like the following:

```
if(arg0.getId() == R.id.buttonId)
{
//Code for this button
}
else if(arg0.getId() == R.id.buttonId2)
{
//Code for second button
}
```

and so on.

Personally, I prefer the second option as you can easily know which button the code belongs to, especially when you have a lot of buttons on a layout.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell my where I can see System.out.println("X") now? Cause it is not in the console.

Comment: Don't use that. Instead, use Log statements like Log.d (debug), Log.e (error), Log.w (warning).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer #3 if possible, IMHO, it's cleaner.  e.g.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:onClick="onButtonClicked" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:onClick="onButtonClicked" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:onClick="onButtonClicked" />
```

Then in your Activity

```
public void onButtonClicked(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.button1:
         break;
       case R.id.button2:
         break;
       case R.id.button3:
         break;
    }
}
```

However, this won't work with the new Fragment design pattern, if you're using Fragment, then stick to option #1, or #2.